# Directshow current position AVIMUX

Tags: c++, delphi, directshow

I am using winsoft WCamera  component with C++ Builder and would like to try and get the current time position from the AVIMUX part of the Directshow graph. Capture is working fine but when I look at the generated file it always seems longer in time than my elapsed time using GetTickCount.

As WCamera component doesn't provide the current media position I am using GetTickCount to give me an approximate position in the video recording to mark events which have occurred.  However I am finding that the video is always longer than the time I measure.  I would like to try and get the current position from the AVI MUX and see if this is more accurate but I am not sure how to do this.

I tried

```cpp
    HRESULT FindFilterInterface(
        IGraphBuilder *pGraph, // Pointer to the Filter Graph Manager.
        REFGUID iid,           // IID of the interface to retrieve.
        void **ppUnk)          // Receives the interface pointer.
{
    if (!pGraph || !ppUnk) return E_POINTER;

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    IEnumFilters *pEnum = NULL;
    IBaseFilter *pF = NULL;
    if (FAILED(pGraph->EnumFilters(&pEnum)))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    // Query every filter for the interface.
    while (S_OK == pEnum->Next(1, &pF, 0))
    {
        hr = pF->QueryInterface(iid, ppUnk);
        pF->Release();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    pEnum->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

But this gives the error

[bcc64 Error] main.cpp(29): non-const lvalue reference to type '_di_IEnumFilters' (aka 'DelphiInterface') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Wdirectshow9::IEnumFilters **'
  WDirectShow9.hpp(1392): passing argument to parameter 'ppEnum' here
[bcc64 Error] main.cpp(34): non-const lvalue reference to type '_di_IBaseFilter' (aka 'DelphiInterface') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Wdirectshow9::IBaseFilter **'
  WDirectShow9.hpp(1402): passing argument to parameter 'ppFilter' here

hpp file defines this as

```cpp
    __interface IEnumFilters;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IEnumFilters> _di_IEnumFilters;
```

Any suggestions as to how I can access the IEnumFilters?

Comment: I have now added the Delphi source from component direct to my c++ builder application and can read the current media position.  This corresponds with my get tick count elapsed time period.  However the AVI file itself is always longer in time than I record.  For instance 20 seconds recoding shows as 28 seconds in the avi file?